# Error during DATE field as key in matchesKeyInQuery Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I got this error message when I try to put a Date field as the key in the **matchesKeyInQuery** method in a CloudCode function.

I have 2 classes, Groups and Joinings and each has a **dateOfVisit** column as a DATE type.

Here are my 2 queries:

```
...
queryGroups.select("placeId", "dateOfVisit");
...
queryUpdatedJoiningsSinceLastJobRan.matchesKeyInQuery("dateOfVisit","dateOfVisit", queryGroups);
queryUpdatedJoiningsSinceLastJobRan.matchesKeyInQuery("placeId","placeId", queryGroups);
...
```

and the error I get:

***operator needs a value type instead of 2015-09-28 16:30:00 +0000 UTC***

It works with the **placeId** key but does not work with the Date value.Am I missing something here?
Can you tell me what should I do about it?
It would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has turned out that this is actually a valid bug in parse. I have reported it and they confirmed it.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/957925427582271/